# Biden's motorcade at COP26

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, joe-biden

I note https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67418/did-the-us-presidential-motorcade-contravene-uk-traffic-regulations which states that the motorcade vehicles had American-style red emergency lights, in possible contravention of British (and other) legislation.

Can anybody provide definite information on whether the vehicles were actually brought into the country for this specific event, rather than being part of a diplomatic pool?

Comment: I'm quite certain that nobody driving around would mistake an American presidential motorcade for anything other than what it is.  Those laws exist to prevent vehicles from, deliberately or otherwise, using confusing, misleading, or deceptive lighting on their vehicle which may cause others to actually believe they are emergency services or police.  The motorcade, on the other hand, is a huge escort that drives a fixed route on roads that are cleared and *closed to all other traffic*.  Nobody will take those red lights the wrong way.

Answer (score 22):

Generally speaking, [yes, the presidential motorcade travels 'with' the president.](https://gmauthority.com/blog/2017/11/how-does-the-secret-service-transport-the-presidents-motorcade-overseas-in-a-giant-transport-craft/)

In actuality it's shipped ahead of his arrival, in military transports designed for armored vehicles.  I don't have evidence to support any direct claim for this exact visit, but it's far more likely than not that the motorcade consisted of Secret Service fleet vehicles, including The Beast, brought over from the U.S.

Also, if the President is overseas for something like COP he's leading a diplomatic mission and thus gets immunity, etc., etc. and breaking domelight laws isn't worth going to war over so there's basically no way anyone's going to make a fuss about it.

Comment: Just FYI, [the beeb is reporting](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/59135899) that he had the beast in both Glasgow and Rome.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please remember that the purpose of comments on answers is [to improve the answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Debates about the subject matter of the answer are off-topic.

Comment: "The Beast" should be "A beast" in the context; only once on the ground is it "The" Beast, and there's many of them.